# CodeIgniter and S3 putObject - getting the right path to file

Tags: php, codeigniter, amazon-s3

I am having trouble passing the correct URL of an image from CI to S3 servers.

My image is stored in the root folder under assets/image.jpg

```
$this->load->library('s3');
$this->s3->putObject('../../image.jpg', $bucket, 'testimage.jpg', 'public-read');
```

The bucket creates the file testimage.jpg however it is just a 20kb file that is corrupt.

Can someone let me know how to get the right path to the image?

I have already tried:`FCPATH . 'asset/image.jpg'` and it did not work.

**NOTE: I am doing this on my localhost, if that matters.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to the question and hopefully it can help someone else some time:

`$this->s3->putObject(S3::inputFile('asset/image.jpg'), $bucket, 'testimage.jpg', 'public-read');`

It was required to put `S3::inputFile('folder/file')`.

Comment: Thanks! I had the same issue, and you solved it for me :-)